# Virtualbox 6.0.14 (Host Win10, Guest Ubuntu 16.04.2) Unity 3D can't enable

Tags: unity3d

The VM works perfectly in VirtualBox5#.
I've tried all tricks I found on google in reinstalling **GuestAddition** and **Enlarge Display Memory**.

Display adapters: NIVIDA NVS 310
Host: Win10 1809

Please share some thoughts.

```
uname -r
4.15.0-72-generic

user@VirtualBox:~$ sudo /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
[sudo] password for user: 
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 18.0.5

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Comment: Just to add my progress on this issue. I've tried searching "OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe" and found discussion pointing to Virtualbox Hardening issue. Unfortunately, I can't touch AV, and could not figure out how to proceed on Hardening issue.

Comment: I rolled back to 5.3.34r. Boot up complete black screen. .log shows 6.0.14r guest addition is called. Went back 6.0.14r and uninstalled GuestAddition then back to 5.3.34r. Still black screen, with similar message in .log. It seem I'm stuck with 6.# with 3D not enabled.